# missing operand before '<' operator in datatable select

Tags: asp.net, linq, datetime, datatable

In the data table there is column that is composite date that has the value of the date with some conditions i want to filter the data table.

The expression that i am making is giving me error .

Expression

```
scaleID=8207 and CompositeDate >= '5/1/2009 6:01:23 PM' And CompositeDate =< '5/31/2009 6:01:23 PM'
```

what is that i am missing here if it cannot be done in this way can we use LINQ for this if yes can any one provide me with the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `=<` when I suspect you mean `<=`.

The [docs for the expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) include `<=`, but I can't see anything to suggest that `=<` is valid.

Personally I would try to avoid magic strings as far as possible and use LINQ instead (even within datatables) but that's a different matter.

Comment: The way I remember it is "It's only ever eyebrows, never mouths".